# Combining weather data with records with different date ranges in R

Tags: r

I have 2 data sets - the first has daily weather information, including mean temperature and heating degree days.  I have a complete set of weather data for each day needed.  A small snippet of the weather data looks like:

```
weather:

weather.station | date       | temp | HDD
A               | 11/30/2013 | 30   | 35
A               | 12/01/2013 | 28   | 37
```

The second data set has a data for a number of homes, each with individual date ranges, that shows fuel consumption per day.  For example:

```
home.bills:

home.id | start.date | end.date   | electric.usage | weather.station
1       | 11/15/2013 | 12/14/2013 |  80            | A
1       | 12/15/2013 | 1/14/2014  |  85            | A
2       | 11/18/2013 | 12/15/2013 |  60            | A
2       | 12/16/2013 | 1/13/2014  |  57            | A
```

I'm looking for an efficient way to combine the two data sets in bulk, so I could extend the home.bills information with weather conditions (for example, mean temp over the date range and sum HDD over the date range).

The output might look like:

```
output:

home.id | start.date | end.date   | electric.usage | mean.temp | sum.HDD
1       | 11/15/2013 | 12/14/2013 |  80            |   32.8    |  937
1       | 12/15/2013 | 1/14/2014  |  85            |   29.7    |  1122
2       | 11/18/2013 | 12/15/2013 |  60            |   31.7    |  944
2       | 12/16/2013 | 1/13/2014  |  57            |   28.8    |  1201
```

Can anyone suggest a dplyer way to join these two data sets?  I know how to do summarize, I don't know how to join the two data over a range of dates.

Comment: Don't understand the Q how you are going to combine the data. E.g. How to make use of the `temp` in `weather` data? The two dates fall into the first date interval of `home.id == 1`. Do you have a desired output and post it here for better understanding?

Comment: The OP notes "for example, mean temp over the date range and sum HDD over the date range", so it seems clear what he's looking for. (I'll admit the example could be a bit more reproducible.)

Comment: Please do not **ever** post data like this in the future (with pipes separating the columns). Importing this into R is a nightmare. Instead post the output of, e.g., `dput(weather)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways to do this. The first uses `sqldf` but requires(??) that you rename the columns (because SQL does not like column names with "."). Conceptually it's simpler though.

```
weather    <- structure(list(weather.station = c("A", "A"), date = c("11/30/2013 ", "12/01/2013 "), temp = c(30, 28), HDD = c(35L, 37L)), .Names = c("weather.station", "date", "temp", "HDD"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
home.bills <- structure(list(home.id = c(1, 1, 2, 2), start.date = c(" 11/15/2013 ", " 12/15/2013 ", " 11/18/2013 ", " 12/16/2013 "), end.date = c(" 12/14/2013 ", " 1/14/2014  ", " 12/15/2013 ", " 1/13/2014  "), electric.usage = c(80, 85, 60, 57), weather.station = c("A", "A", "A", "A")), .Names = c("home.id", "start.date", "end.date", "electric.usage", "weather.station"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

# dates need to be Dates, not character
weather$date <- as.Date(weather$date,format="%m/%d/%Y")
home.bills$start.date <- as.Date(home.bills$start.date,format="%m/%d/%Y")
home.bills$end.date   <- as.Date(home.bills$end.date,format="%m/%d/%Y")

# sqldf does not like "." in column names!!!
colnames(weather) <- gsub(".","_",colnames(weather),fixed=T)
colnames(home.bills) <- gsub(".","_",colnames(home.bills),fixed=T)

library(sqldf)
sqldf("select a.*, avg(temp) as mean_temp, sum(HDD) as sum_HDD
      from [home.bills] a join weather b 
      on b.date>=a.start_date and b.date<=a.end_date 
        and a.weather_station=b.weather_station
      group by home_id, start_date, end_date")
#   home_id start_date   end_date electric_usage weather_station mean_temp sum_HDD
# 1       1 2013-11-15 2013-12-14             80               A        29      72
# 2       2 2013-11-18 2013-12-15             60               A        29      72
```

The second uses the `foverlaps(...)` functionality in the `data.table` package. This is extremely powerful and extremely fast. Note that this soluton is almost identical to one posted by @akrun a couple of hours ago and then deleted (I'd love to know why??).

```
# data.table solution
weather    <- structure(list(weather.station = c("A", "A"), date = c("11/30/2013 ", "12/01/2013 "), temp = c(30, 28), HDD = c(35L, 37L)), .Names = c("weather.station", "date", "temp", "HDD"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
home.bills <- structure(list(home.id = c(1, 1, 2, 2), start.date = c(" 11/15/2013 ", " 12/15/2013 ", " 11/18/2013 ", " 12/16/2013 "), end.date = c(" 12/14/2013 ", " 1/14/2014  ", " 12/15/2013 ", " 1/13/2014  "), electric.usage = c(80, 85, 60, 57), weather.station = c("A", "A", "A", "A")), .Names = c("home.id", "start.date", "end.date", "electric.usage", "weather.station"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

library(data.table) >= 1.9.4
# convert to data.tables and convert date to Date
setDT(weather)[,date:=as.Date(date,format="%m/%d/%Y")]
setDT(home.bills)[,(2:3):=lapply(.SD,as.Date,format="%m/%d/%Y"),.SDcols=2:3]
# need start.date and end.date in weather data.table (both = date)
weather[,c("start.date","end.date"):=list(date,date)]
setkey(home.bills,weather.station,start.date,end.date)
# calaculate overlaps
result <- foverlaps(weather,home.bills,nomatch=0)
# aggregate
result[,list(mean.temp=mean(temp),sum.HDD=sum(HDD)),
       by=list(home.id,start.date,end.date,electric.usage,weather.station)]
#    home.id start.date   end.date electric.usage weather.station mean.temp sum.HDD
# 1:       1 2013-11-15 2013-12-14             80               A        29      72
# 2:       2 2013-11-18 2013-12-15             60               A        29      72
```

Comment: sqldf does not itself transform column names with dots.  If you used sqldf with any database other than SQLite then the names were not transformed.  It was RSQLite that did that but since RSQLite 1.0 RSQLite no longer does.